# Program not terminating loop in recursion after base condition is met

Tags: c, recursion, while-loop

Why is the control returning to the top of the program after the base condition is met? It should just execute the line present after the recursive call. {output 54322233} shows that control is returning back to the top of the code:

```
    void print(int a)
    {while(a!=1)
    {
    printf("%d",a);
    a--;
    print(a);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is implementing ***both*** recursion and iteration!  Let's separate out the two:

Iteration:

```
void print(int a)
{
    while (a >= 1)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a);
        a--;
    }
}
```

Recursion:

```
void print(int a)
{
    if (a >= 1)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a);
        print(a - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: so each time i make a recursion call iam create a while loop within in a recursive loop

Comment: lets say i enter 3 the code prints 3 a-- update the value of variable to 2 and then 2 goes in the recursive call and it enters another while loop which

Comment: prints 2 update the value of the variable to 1 and calls recursion and 1 goes into another while loop condition falls to true it exits the code and does not return back to the place where the function call was made

Comment: instead it goes back to the top of the code and prints 2 again cus the value of the variable is 2 for that while loop

Comment: so if use return after the recursive call statement then the while loop will run only once for each recursive call

Comment: yep break and return both seems to do the trick and now the code runs just fine

Comment: @ozzy, if you add an unconditional `break` or `return` to a `while()` loop to make it only run once, it's effectively an `if` statement, so you might was well use an `if` statement (see my recursive example.)

Answer (score -1):

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void print(int a);

int main() {

int a = 10;
print(10);
```

}
     void print(int a)
    {
        while(a != 5)

```
a--;
cout << a << endl;
}
```

//The value of a should be greater than 5
//So the recursion will stop at 5

Comment: The recursion won't stop at 5 as there is no recursion here to begin with!